# Формула для Excel

Tags: excel

Для того чтобы распространить на всю таблицу формулу, что бы она работала следующим образом:

есть например столбец из цифр 1 2 3 4 5 6. Что бы 1 2 3 были вместе, а начиная с 4 уже для 4 5 6. То есть в столбце они вместе

Что нужно сделать? Может я малость непонятно написал, приведу пример на фото.

[image]
<sub>(источник: [upyourpic.org](http://upyourpic.org/images/201211/c69u1cf35v.jpg))</sub>

0+7+0 сравниваем с 7, если равно то 0/7 7/7 0/7. Затем 0+6+1 сравниваем с 7, раз равно то 0/7 6/7 1/7. НО если например для этого столбца так 0+3+3, получаем 6, а оно не равно 7, то делаем уже следующие 0/6 3/6 3/6. В другом столбце уже не 7 ключевое, а 26. Теперь надеюсь понятно, что я хочу получить. Очень прошу помочь.

Comment: @Serg121, непонятно

Comment: Что именно?

Comment: @Serg121, "приведу пример на фото." Где фото?:)

Comment: вот же оно

Comment: @Serg121, не вижу. Куда смотреть?

Comment: @stck, у вас, видимо, mail.ru блокируется. 
http://upyourpic.org/images/201211/c69u1cf35v.jpg

Comment: @lampa, да... Не придал внимания alt text

Answer (score 1):

Для чего ключевое число? Ведь в любом случае запись имеет вид:
*число/сумма_трех_чисел*...

Предположим, что ячейка с буквой *А* - *А5*.

Без учета ключевого числа формула такая:
    =C5&"/"&СУММ(ВЫБОР(B5;C5:C7;C4:C6;C3:C5))

Суммируемый диапазон выбирается в зависимости от числа в столбце *В* текущей строки.

Comment: Хм, логично. Спасибо.